# Is there a way to allow Powershell to "buffer" commands?

Tags: powershell

When using the CMD prompt, you can "type ahead" commands and when the current operation is finished, the command will be issued to the CMD prompt.

When you execute the following in CMD, foo will run, then bar will run.  However in PowerShell, it will ignore `bar.exe<ENTER>` because foo is running.  Is there a way around this?  It's pretty frustrating to have to wait for a command to finish before executing a subsequent command.

```
foo.exe<ENTER> (takes 60 secs)
bar.exe<ENTER>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the host. In the console host (`powershell.exe`) it works the same as `cmd` (the way you want it to). In ISE (`powershell_ise.exe`) it does not.

You won't be able to change this behavior.

Your workaround then is to use the console host instead of ISE for interactively typing commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you're going to run both, write  `foo.exe; bar.exe`

Or write them both in the ISE edit window, and press F5 to run.